# session attribute in controller is null but in jsp it has value

Tags: java, spring, jsp, session, model-view-controller

here is a controller login_action

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login_action")
    public ModelAndView login_action(@RequestParam("email") String email,@RequestParam("password") String password,RedirectAttributes redir){
        ModelAndView model=new ModelAndView("WEB-INF/view/index");
        Configuration con = new Configuration().configure().addAnnotatedClass(Users.class);
        SessionFactory sf=  con.buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sf.openSession();
        Query q=session.createSQLQuery("SELECT User_ID,User_First_Name,User_Last_Name,Email,User_Type,Program,Level,Gender FROM Users  WHERE Email=:email AND Password=:password");
        q.setParameter("email",email);
        q.setParameter("password",password);
        Object u = (Object) q.uniqueResult();
        if(u==null) {
            model.addObject("view","login");
            model.addObject("errorMsg","Incorect Email or Password");
        }else {
                model=new ModelAndView("redirect:/profile");
                redir.addFlashAttribute("user",u);
        }
        return model;
    }
```

It sets user into session and redirect to profile after matching email and password

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/profile")
    public ModelAndView profile(HttpSession session){
        Object [] o=(Object[])session.getAttribute("user");
        if(o==null){
            ModelAndView model =new ModelAndView("redirect:/login");
            return model;
        }
        ModelAndView model=new ModelAndView("WEB-INF/view/index");
        model.addObject("title",o[1]+" "+o[2]+" - Profile");
        model.addObject("view","profile");
        return model;
    }
```

When it is redirected to profile user attribute is null. So it redirects to login even though I have set user in session.

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/login")
    public ModelAndView login(){
        ModelAndView model=new ModelAndView("WEB-INF/view/index");
        model.addObject("title","Login");
        model.addObject("view","login");
        return model;
    }
```

But in my header.jsp , user is set in session

```
    <c:choose>
    <c:when test="${user!=null}">
        <a>
            Welcome, ${user[1]} ||<a href="profile">profile</a></a> <a href="logout"/>Logout</a>
        </div>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <div>
            <a href="/"/>Home</a>||<a href="login"/>Login</a>||<a href="signup"/>Sign Up</a>
        </div>
    </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
    <hr>
```

But when I click the link to profile , it works 
Why?
Login page:-

[image]

After login in, the page is redirected to the profile and login again because user is null in controller
But the header change because in jsp there is value in user
[image]

And when I click profile it works

[image]

Comment: You didn't put anything in the session, you added something to flash attributes.

Comment: but in jsp it is printing user name from session

Comment: No it isn't. It is printing the user from the flash variables, which after the redirect are added as request attributes. When doing things like `${user.property}` what happens is that first the request scope is checked, page scoped, session scoped and finally application scope (check the servlet spec for this).

Comment: Then could you please explain why it is not redirecting to login page when i click profile after logging in. the profile controller should redirect to login page if user was null or not set

Comment: because there is nothing in the session...

Comment: i don't want to be disrespectful but if there was nothing on session the profile controller was supposed to redirect to login but it is not redirecting. it means there is value in session. could you please review profile controller in question please!

Comment: I doubt this is all your code and I suspect t you are putting an array in the session somewhere which is why the check fails. You are **nowhere in the code shown** here putting something in the session. The `HttpSession` that is (which is something totally different as the `Session` from hibernate). On another note imho your code is flawed why use hibernate if you aren working around it, you are mixing things and if you really want to implement security you should be using a `HandlerInterceptor` (or even better use Spring Security instead of reinventing the wheel).